# onClick is not getting triggered in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The click does not seem to trigger the console.log().

```
import React from 'react';

import './SearchResult.scss';

const searchResult = props => {
    const listItemClicked = () => {
        console.log('hi');
    };

    return (
        <li key={props.resultName} className="result-list" onClick={() => listItemClicked()}>
            <div className="result">
                <p>{props.resultName[0].toUpperCase() + props.resultName.slice(1)}</p>
            </div>
        </li>
    );
};

export default searchResult;
```

Maybe its been a long day but I just can't get the onClick to trigger the console.log...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Based on your code, `console.log()` should be trigger when you click on `li`

Comment: @ErtanHasani I thought so, its something so simple but for some odd reason I just can't get it to trigger...

Comment: Try re-starting your compiler. That often helps when you're 100% sure that something should work.

Comment: will this work: "onClick={listItemClicked}" (without  apostophes)

Comment: as @ErtanHasani said your code should trigger `console.log()` when you click on `li` (I just tested it)
maybe you are filtering your log?

Comment: Check the style, maybe you have `pointer-events: none;` on `.result-list` or `li`

Comment: Yeah, thats why I am so confused because no matter what I try, I can not get that to trigger... Thanks anyway guys for your time, il try figure it out and write the answer to the issue behind this...

Comment: Aren't you getting a console warning from React? Components have to start with capital letters...

Comment: It's actually does trigger the console.log - check https://codesandbox.io/s/9oxm28w48p

Comment: Yeah thats why I have had to ask because it works everywhere but not at this precise point and I can not figure it out...

Comment: @Andrew check `css` for `pointer-events: none`

Comment: @ErtanHasani I have got the CSS infront of me, pointer-events is not defined there what should I set it as instead of none if you think none could be the issue?

Comment: `pointer-events: all;`

Comment: @ErtanHasani still nothing, maybe its to do with the way the component itself gets rendered but i am not sure...

Comment: This is the a gist of how the component gets called - https://gist.github.com/ElAndy94/fb73ec885456d2af4f6e1326c98d53b7     Line 1-3 shows the creation and line 28 shows how it got rendered.

Comment: Right okay the issue is coming from the component before this one has a property which if the search box is not on focus and its onBlur then display = none;  This seems to be what was not letting it get triggered when I was clicking the `li` I am guessing it was getting the onBlur property which gives it display:none

Answer (score 0):

Add default props in your above code.

Code will be like:

```
import React from 'react';
import './SearchResult.scss';

const SearchResult = props => {
    const listItemClicked = () => {
         console.log('hi');
    };

    return (
         <li key={props.resultName} className="result-list" onClick={() =>listItemClicked()}>
            <div className="result">
               <p>{props.resultName[0].toUpperCase() + props.resultName.slice(1)}</p>
            </div>
        </li>
    );
};

SearchResult.defaultProps = {
  resultName:["abc","xyz"]
}

export default SearchResult;
```